# Administrator account renamed to administrator.domain in domain user computer

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

i have domain controller with 3 computer connected to it(for LAB and Test purpose use only)
when i connect to my client and enter administrator@domainname.com as user name after login my command prompt become `C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAINNAME>`
[image]
also there is folder with same name in C:\user
[image]

is there any way to bring back my main Administrator account in this Domain Computer??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Administrator* account was not renamed.

The reason you see `Administrator.ZARRAFE` is that you have logged on with the local Administrator first and then with the domain Administrator. Since they cannot share the same profile folder, because they are different accounts, the operating system will append a suffix (the domain name the account belongs to) to following profile folders with the same account name.

That is normal behaviour and you should not try to change this.

Comment: reason is i login to domain when domain controller is not accessible,but i search for find a way to remove Administrator.ZARRAFE and login to Administrator it self

Comment: So logon with `COMPUTERNAME\Administrator` instead of `ZARRAFE\Administrator`.

Comment: By the way, having the domain controller offline for an extended period of time is not something that should be taken with a shrug. So usually, before you log on to any computer using the local account, one usually tries to find out why the domain controller is offline.

Comment: @AminM Log off and delete both the `C:\Users\Administrator` and `C:\Users\Administrator.ZARRAFE` folders from another computer. Use the command `rd /s` to recursively delete the directories.  Then connect to the registry hive remotely from another computer and knock out `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-xxx-xxx-xxx`, and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\S-1-5-21-xxx`.  Now log back on with the domain administrator and NOT the local admin.

Comment: @Daniel i know! but i want to log in with domain account

Comment: So log in with ZARRAFE\Administrator. What do you not understand?

Comment: @Daniel yes.so you tell me the only solution is "when i join domain ,never login to local account unless i disjoin from domain.am i right?